# EF4 inserting NULLs to SQL Server tables via Function Import

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a complex type, with all string properties

```
// Actual class is auto-generated from Model1.tt,
// this is what the class looks like conceptually:
public class Product
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I've done a function import of a stored procedure. Here's the stored procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[CreateProduct]
    @ID           nvarchar(50),
    @Name         nvarchar(50),
    @Description  nvarchar(255)
as
begin tran
insert [dbo].[Products](
    ID,
    Name,
    Description
)
values (
    @ID,
    @Name,
    @Description
)
commit tran
go
```

My function import has the following signature:

```
 CreateProduct(string ID, string Name, string Descritpion);
```

I'm calling it like this (as a test):

```
void AddProduct(Product product)
{
    entities.CreateProduct(product.ID, product.Name, product.Description);
}

void Test()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    var product = new Product
    {
        ID          = string.Format("ID-{0}", now),
        Name        = string.Format("Name-{0}", now),
        Description = string.Format("Description-{0}", now)
    }

    AddProduct(product);
}
```

My problem is, when I look at what's inserted into the database (SQL Server 2008), I'm getting the following values:

```
ID          10/11/2011 10:35:46 AM
Name        NULL
Description NULL

// Note, the ID string is not 'ID-10/11/2011 10:35:46 AM' ('ID-' in front)
```

Comment: The syntax for SQL INSERT is `INSERT INTO table (column1, [column2, ... ]) VALUES (value1, [value2, ... ])`. You are missing the `INTO` keyword.

Comment: @Thomas Li, `INTO` is optional: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Comment: No, INTO is not necessary. These stored procedures are already tested elsewhere, and work fine.

Comment: On an unrelated note, your transaction isn't necessary since all DML operations are atomic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supidity, another test was failing (unrelated), but was causing the issue. Not sure why, but resolving the other test, fixed this problem.